# DocuSign API viewing FullName

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am developing an app with DocuSign eSignature SDK for C#. Everything works fine, except for one thing. I have 2 signers. The first one has most of the tabs, which displays correctly. What I need to do is be able to view the FullName of the Signer 2 from the view of the Signer 1. Is this possible? I tried adding a text for the fullname of signer 2 in signer 1 view, but that creates a duplicate when Signer 2 is viewing the document.

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to do this, how about you [use Document Generation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-document-generation/)?

With this feature you can customize your document and add a field called say {{Signer2Name}} that you set the value for BEFORE you send the document for signature.

This will also later allow for many other customizations of the document, but for now - will let you do what you want.

The C# code for this can be found in GitHub - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/DocumentGeneration.cs